# <li> tags in HTML improper behaviour

Tags: html, css

There is a lot of space before & after the li {audi, bmw, etc} TAGs.i want to remove it but its not getting removed.
& the image in the 2nd li tag which is used as bullet has gone out of the screen.

So pls. can anybody help me fix this 2 problems

http://i42.tinypic.com/b5k27s.jpg

HTML CODE :

```
    <html>
<`head>`
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "myStyle2.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#ul1
{
list-style-image:url('1.bmp');
padding:0px;
float:left;
}
</style>

<title>CARS</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class = "container" style=width: "100%">

<div class = "header" height = "20%" width = "100%">
CARS
</div>

<div class = "list" height = "10%" width = "100%">
    <ul class ="ul2">
<li><a href = "#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href = "bmw.htm">BMW</a></li>
<li><a href = "audi.htm">AUDI</a></li>
<li><a href = "pors.htm">PORSCHE</a></li>
<li><a href = "lamb.htm">LAMBORGHINI</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<ul id = "ul1">
<li>AUDI</li>
<li>PORSCHE</li>
<li>BMW</li>
<li>LAMBORGHI   NI</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS code :

```
@font-face
{
font-family: nsecthin;
src : url('nsecthin.ttf')
}
body
{
margin:10px;
background-color:green;
}
.header
{
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:black;
text-decoration:underline;
font-family:nsecthin,Constantia;
font-size:2.0em;
letter-spacing:3px;
font-weight:bold;
text-indent: 0;
line-height:50px;
background-color:yellow;
border:2px solid white;
}
.list
{

font-family:constantia;
font-size:2em;
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:2px solid white;

}

.ul2 li
{
height:2px;
list-style-type:none;
float:none;
width:100%;
display:inline;
border:2px solid white;
}

.ul2 a
{
float:none;
width:1em;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
display:inline;
background-color:blue;
padding-left:0;
border:2px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `width:100%;` on the `.ul2 li` in your css.
`

Answer (score 0):

Try `list-style-position:inside;` for your list item, if that is what you mean.

Comment: `list-style-position: inside;` to be specific might solve the problem. But making the `li` narrower, and adding a `margin-left` would be a better solution.

Comment: btw: why does you beginning head tag has quotes in it, and `style=width: "100%">` you should change quotes to `style="width=100%;"` to produce correct syntax

Comment: @david: what you mean with narrower? Like `width:80%;` and `margin-left:20%;` for list item?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Although it might be that it's the `ul` that requires the margin.

Comment: @sewo sorry this dint help.
i am posting an image pls check it out

Answer (score 0):

Strip out margins and padding altogether:

```
ul , li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then tweak as necessary:

```
#ul1 li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Also try to reserve styling information to CSS (like height/width attributes).

Comment: i've already removed margin & padding too.
but it dint help.

as u can see in the image, it is not due to margin, its something else

Comment: Try stripping it out of everything:

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

Comment: Oh wait, the space is because you have the height and width set in the attributes. Remove those from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have margins-top and margin-bottom on your ul-element. After using `ul{margin:0;}` it works for me.

It's the browser standard styles defining them.

You know about Firebug or tools like that, right? learn to use it!

Heard about reset.css or normalize.css, read more about that:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/